# Multiple items with different tax rates on a PayPal Website Payments Standard button

Tags: paypal, e-commerce, shopping-cart

I am creating an **e-shop builder**, i.e. a site where a user creates their site and e-shop.  The products are entered into my custom CMS by the person who builds the e-shop. I ask the shop builder to link the shop to their PayPal account by entering their e-mail.

I am currently trying to create a **checkout button** for my cart.

Problem is, **multiple products might have different tax rates**, for instance alcoholic beverages might have a 13% tax rate whereas other products have 23%. Is there a way to incorporate this in the post request?

Ideally what I would like to do is this:

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">

    <input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="Some product">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number_1" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="20.00" />
    <input type="hidden" name="tax_rate_1" value="23">

    <input type="hidden" name="item_name_2" value="Some alcoholic product">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number_2" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount_2" value="15.00" />
    <input type="hidden" name="tax_rate_2" value="13">

    <!-- other fields omitted for brevity -->
</form>
```

The `tax_rate_1` and `tax_rate_2` fields are hypothetical, I don't know if something like this is possible.

If I RTFM'ed correctly, setting per-item tax rates should be possible *if* you register the products yourself in the PayPal website interface. This is exactly what I am trying to avoid, because the products are entered by the end user on my CMS.

If what I want isn't possible with a *Website Payments Standard* button, I would also welcome other ideas on how to forward such orders to PayPal. I am trying to avoid the *Express Checkout* payment product because *if I understand correctly* I won't have full control of the cart. I want to have a custom cart and later be able to offer more payment options besides PayPal.

Please help in any way you can! I am a total noob with PayPal.

Comment: Also, would it be OK if I calculate prices plus tax for each item, set those to `amount_1`, `amount_2`, etc., and then set the global tax rate to zero? Is this a viable strategy? I'm still brainstorming here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, what I want is indeed possible and [is described in the manual](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/cart_upload/#id08A3FA00X7Q). In my situation where I have built a custom shopping cart, I want to use the *Cart upload* command of the *Website Payments Standard* product.

To do a "cart upload" I've set the following fields:

```
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
<input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
```

The variables are `tax_1`, `tax_2`, etc. They need to be specified as currency, not percentage.